# SAS transpose using a part of the name

Tags: sas, dataset, transpose

I'm here asking for help for a problem with proc transpose.

I have a dataset made this way (I'm going to show only 3 variables but I have lots of them)

```
PR  ID  VAR1a   VAR1b   VAR1c   VAR2a   VAR2b   VAR2c   VAR3a   VAR3b VAR3c 
1   1   x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x     x
1   2   x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x     x
1   3   x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x     x
2   1   x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x     x
2   2   x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x     x
2   3   x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x     x
```

I need an output dataset like this:

```
PREID   ID  VAR(name)   A   B   C
1       1   VAR1(name)  x   x   x
1       1   VAR2(name)  x   x   x
1       1   VAR3(name)  x   x   x
1       2   VAR1(name)  x   x   x
1       2   VAR2(name)  x   x   x
1       2   VAR3(name)  x   x   x
1       3   VAR1(name)  x   x   x
1       3   VAR2(name)  x   x   x
1       3   VAR3(name)  x   x   x
```

etc with preid 2 id 1 2 3, preid 3 id 1 2 3.

So I need to transpose but using the name (discriminating from a b c), I really have no idea from where I could start.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @sushil solution above, but one less step. Since you have to go into a data step anyways, you may as well transpose the data in that step as well. So in this solution the Proc Transpose/Data step are combined. If you had few enough variables I'd remove the last transpose as well, but this is more flexible if you have quite a few variables.

```
data input;
infile datalines dsd dlm=',' missover;
input PR    :$8. 
      ID    :$8.  
      VAR1a :$8.  
      VAR1b :$8.  
      VAR1c :$8.   
      VAR2a :$8.  
      VAR2b :$8.  
      VAR2c :$8.  
      VAR3a :$8.  
      VAR3b :$8. 
      VAR3c :$8.;
datalines4;
1,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
1,2,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
1,3,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
2,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
2,2,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
2,3,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
;;;;
run;

data out1;
set input;
array vars(*) var1a--var3c;
do i=1 to dim(vars);
name=vname(vars(i));
varname=substr(name,1,length(name)-1);
group=substr(name,length(name));
value=vars(i);
output;
end;

drop var1a--var3c;
run;

proc transpose data=out1 out=out2;
by pr id varname;
id group;
var value;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

If i'm able to understand the output correctly. I think to achieve the result, first each observation of your input data would be broken into several different observation. So single observation would be converted into 9(var1a to var3c) observations( You can achive that using proc transpose by pr & id variable and transpose var1a to var3c variables). After this using a datastep, you would need to break _NAME__ variable into var1/2/3 and the a/b/c.  After getting this done, you should be able to transpose the data to achieve your result.

I tried to write down the code based on your input data. Let me know if it helps.

```
data input;
infile datalines dsd dlm=',' missover;
input PR    :$8. 
      ID    :$8.  
      VAR1a :$8.  
      VAR1b :$8.  
      VAR1c :$8.   
      VAR2a :$8.  
      VAR2b :$8.  
      VAR2c :$8.  
      VAR3a :$8.  
      VAR3b :$8. 
      VAR3c :$8.;
datalines4;
1,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
1,2,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
1,3,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
2,1,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
2,2,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
2,3,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x
;;;;
run;
proc transpose data=input out=staging ;
by  pr id ;
var VAR1a--VAR3c;
run;

data staging;
    set staging;
    var=substrn(strip(_name_),1,length(strip(_name_))-1);
    dummy=substrn(strip(_name_),length(strip(_name_)),1);

    drop _name_;
run;
proc transpose data=staging out=final(drop=_name_);
    by pr id var;
    id dummy;
    var  col1;
run;

proc print data=final;run;
```